# Modal isn't shown until Datatables jQuery is finished

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I'm having troubles implementing Datatables jQuery (version 1.10) to an ASP NET Project.
The thing is I'm loading all the necessary configuration in a master JavaScript file.

I first bind all the data in a Gridview and then, automatically, the JavaScript file mentioned above is executed.

**My problem is (since I can't use AJAX because of my back-end structure) I need to bind ALL the data in the gridview in codebehind (C#) and, once the data is already bound, apply the JavaScript script.** It all works fine. However, it takes some time since the data is bound until the CSS and JavaScript of datatable is ready. And in the meantime, the gridview is shown to the user with awful style so I want to avoid this since it's not good for user experience.

I'm trying this (in JavaScript)

```
openModal('id_modal');
load_datatable('id_table'); //function that loads all necessary for 
                            //datatables
```

But the modal appears AFTER load_datatable finishes. I don't know what it may be causing that.

It's worth mentioning that the **master JavaScript is working fine**. The styles are applied successfully but, again, without showing the modal.

The modal I want to pop up is

```
<div class="modal fade" id="id_modal">
        <div class="text-center">
            <asp:Image ID="imgLoading" runat="server" 
              ImageUrl="~/img/loading.svg" AlternateText="Loading..." 
               ToolTip="Loading ..." CssClass="imageLoading" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've also tried a simple modal without an image, without ASP control, etc. but nothing happens.

Comment: it looks like openModal is asynchronous, you may need to pass in a callback function (ie: load_datatable) to openModal to invoke after it is complete

Comment: If you are using bootstrap modals, then you will need to listen to the 'shown.bs.modal' event, and then call load_datatable in the event handler

Comment: I've also did that: $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){load_datatable('id_table')}); but it's not catching any event

Comment: and, of course,  $('#id_modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){load_datatable('id_table')});

Comment: I removed the class 'fade' from modal and it catch the event. However, it's still not working. The modal is poping up after the datatables

Comment: Can you try pushing the callback onto the event queue? It should be: `setTimeout(function() { load_datatable('id_table'); }, 0);`

Comment: Yes, I've also tried this. I execute `$('#id_modal').modal('show');` and then inside setTimeout I execute `load_datatable('id');`. But it's the same. The modal is only shown after datatables script.

Comment: Can you try a synchronous function such as $('#id_modal').show()? Also, is load_datatable being called only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a partial solution.

In Master Page I created

```
<div class="loader"></div>
```

Placed at the top of the HTML code.

Then in masterPage.css I've defined the class:

```
    .loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: #212529;
    background: /*HERE IT GOES THE IMAGE YOU WANT TO DISPLAY*/
    opacity: .9;
}
```

And, finally, in my Master.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //DO ALL THE STUFF YOU NEED
    //AND AT THE END

    $('.loader').hide();     
});
```

**It will show the modal everytime a web form is being loaded and hide it when all the HTML is loaded.**